# Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING]

Tags: java, ejb, jboss7.x

I created two projects: server-side and client-side. I've got a success by deploying server-side, but I can't connect to it from client. Here is my code:

RemoteCalculator.java:

```
package com.calculator;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface RemoteCalculator {
    int add( int op1, int op2 );
}
```

---

CalculatorBean.java:

```
package com.calculator;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class CalculatorBean implements RemoteCalculator {
    @Override
    public int add( int op1, int op2 ) {
        return op1 + op2;
    }
}
```

---

I assembled it with maven. Here I show you invoking part:

EJB_Client.java:

```
public class EJBClient {
    private static void invokeStatelessBean() throws NamingException {
        RemoteCalculator statelessRemoteCalculator = lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator();
        int sum = statelessRemoteCalculator.add( 3, 4 );
        System.out.println( "sum = " + sum );
    }

    private static RemoteCalculator lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator() throws NamingException {
        Security.addProvider( new JBossSaslProvider() );
        final Hashtable<String, String> p = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        p.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://127.0.0.1:1099" );
        p.put( Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming" );
        p.put( Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "admin" );
        p.put( Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "jboss" );
        final Context context = new InitialContext( p );

        return ( RemoteCalculator ) context
            .lookup( "java:/ejb-remote-stateless-1.0-SNAPSHOT/CalculatorBean!com.calculator.RemoteCalculator" );
}

    public static void main( String... args ) throws NamingException {
        invokeStatelessBean();
    }
}
```

---

On running main-method, I got this log:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to create remoting connection [Root exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING]
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.ClientUtil.namingException(ClientUtil.java:36)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:121)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:684)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
    at Main.lookupRemoteStatelessCalculator(Main.java:31)
    at Main.main(Main.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Operation failed with status WAITING
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:89)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.NamingStoreCache.getRemoteNamingStore(NamingStoreCache.java:56)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateCachedNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.java:166)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getOrCreateNamingStore(InitialContextFactory.java:139)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(InitialContextFactory.java:104)
    ... 11 more
```

Please, tell me, what is wrong?

Comment: I also faced this issue. It seems to be a bug with jboss and when this happens you're not able to connect to jboss_cli also (port closed) and jboss process hangs. Restarting (killing the jboss process) the server helps temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and what solved it for me was to add the user to the "application-roles.properties" file.